# Indefinite integral of fraction

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working through some indefinite integral exercises.  There is one here that I can't seem to figure, and there is no solution in the textbook:

$$\int \frac{3}{4x^2+4}dx$$

I'm assuming it has something to do with the corollary

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{fx}dx = \ln|f(x)|+c, where f(x) \ne 0$$

I've tried working backwards by using the chain rule on $\frac{d}{dx} \ln|f(x)|$, but I can't seem to get an answer that satisfies me (or the equation).

Any help?

Comment: Factor out 3/4.  Does this look like an identity involving an inverse trig function?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $\frac{d}{dx} (  \text{arctan x}) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Aha!  Thanks!  I thought there was a rule somewhere I was overlooking.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3}{4x^2+4}dx = \frac{3}{4}\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Now Let $x=\tan \phi\;,$ Then $dx = \sec^2 \phi d\phi$ and Integral change into $\displaystyle I = \frac{3}{4}\int\frac{\sec^2 \phi d\phi}{1+\tan^2 \phi}$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{3}{4}\int\frac{\sec^2 \phi}{\sec^2 \phi}d\phi = \frac{3}{4}\int 1d \phi = \frac{3}{4}\phi+\mathcal{C} = \frac{3}{4}\tan^{-1}x+\mathcal {C}$

Comment: Why to mess up with substitution if the integral is already an immediate one? $$\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx=\arctan x+C$$